# Get ancestor/source of copied Google Doc?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

If you make a copy of a Google Doc, is there a way to get the `fileId` of the original/ancestor/parent/whatever you wanna call it?

I can't seem to find anything. :(  Any know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no API to get the `fileId` of a copied Drive file.

No connection to the Parent file is included in the returned [`File resource`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) other than the `name` that has `Copy of` + `<Copied file name>`. But all that is useless once the name is changed.